# How do you say "I mean", as in "that is not what I mean" ?

Tags: mandarin

As in "You have misunderstood, what I mean is that...."

Comment: `你误解了，我的意思是...`

Comment: “that is not what I mean” 这个不是我的意思。| What I mean is... 我的意思就是... | What do you mean? 你是什么意思？

Comment: The natural way is 我不是这个意思

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,there is not a statement of 'I mean' in 'That is not what I mean'.

In Chinese, 'That is not what I mean.' is '那不是我的意思。'.

So, '我的意思' is just 'what I mean'.